# (Ubunth 16.04) graphic driver (for Geforce 1080ti) is uninstalled after reboot

Tags: 16.04, drivers, updates, graphics

Software: 
- Ubuntu 16.04
- nvidia graphic driver 384.90

Hardware:
- VGA: ZOTAC AM P EXTREM E GeForce GTX 1080 Ti D5X 11GB
- SSD: Samsung 960 PRO M .2 2280 (512GB)
- M/B: ASUS STRIX X99 GAM ING iBORA
- CPU: Intel high-end desktop 6850K (broadwell-E)

**The issue:**
The issue is as follows: I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and on it I installed graphic driver (by `.run`), CUDA 8.0, CUDNN 5.1, tensorflow. And they worked very fine. (Rebooting made no issue this time.) And then after using for some days, I restarted my computer. Then boom. There is no graphic driver and the resolution got bad, and I cannot login...

So I formatted my computer and reinstalled everything. And again, some days later I rebooted. Then there is no graphic driver, the resolution failed.

**So why is this happening? Is it because of some auto updates? How can I avoid such a problem?**

Note that when I install Ubuntu, I need to manually change VGA setting because Ubuntu 16.04 is not really compatible with my VGA. ("Replace 'quiet splash ---' by 'quiet splash nomodeset'")

Comment: Try installing the `nouveau` driver. Go to the start menu and type `Additional Drivers` and then select `nouveau`. That could be a temporary fix.

Comment: Try different drivers.

Comment: my guess is you are running a new kernel. You have to re-install the nvidia driver by running the .run file with each and every kernel update.

Comment: @jkabrg As far as I remember, I blacklisted it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen How can I stop it? And is it okay to stop it? Anyway please note that right after installing drivers and etc, not a thing makes problem. Even if I do 'sodu apt get update' things seem fine. And restarting does not uninstall the driver. But after some days without using my PC, I reboot the pc. Then no driver is found.

Comment: It is either a bug with the closed source nvidia driver or you had a kernel update at some point, I can not tell from what you posted. Look in /boot or check your apt logs.